# How to handle incoming http requests on loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, loopbackjs

I am using loopback and building a login page. The client side files have the login page
$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('#login').click(function(){

    var username = $('#usr').val();
    var password = $('#pwd').val();     

    $.get("http://server,{
        user_type:1,
        username:username,
        password:password
    },function(data,status,xhr){
        console.log("Request was "+status);
        console.log("Result : "+data.login_type);
        console.log("UserId : "+data.user_id);


        if(dat.login_type == 'success'){
            // Redirect to other server
        }
    });     

});
```

})

this is hosted on localhost:3000, when a http request is made to this server , how can i get the incoming request object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send data from client to server node js, loopback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852476/how-to-send-data-from-client-to-server-node-js-loopback)

Comment: My question is different, i want to know how i can handle and route incoming requests on the loopback server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Add-a-static-web-page.html) you have description how to add a static web page 
and [here](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Add-a-custom-Express-route.html) how add a simple Express routing